# Как сделать проверку, запустилась ли функция updateCart()?

Tags: ajax, javascript

В сценарий подгружается файл с содержимым:

```
$(function () {

    function updateCart(data)
    {
        $(".cart-total").html(data.total);
        if (data.discount_numeric) {
            $(".cart-discount").closest('tr').show();
        }
        $(".cart-discount").html('&minus; ' + data.discount);
        $(".affiliate").hide();
    }
    $(".cart a.delete").click(function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        $.post('delete/', {id: tr.data('id')}, function (response) {
            if (response.data.count == 0) {
                location.reload();
            }
            tr.remove();
            updateCart(response.data);
        }, "json");
        return false;
    });

});
```

Файл этот - стандартный, его изменять нельзя.
Как сделать проверку, запустилась ли функция `updateCart()`?

Пробовал:

```
$.when( updateCart() ).done(function( ) {
    alert( 123 ); 
});
```

Но почему-то не находит функцию `updateCart()`:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: updateCart is not defined
```

Comment: У вас там `$(".affiliate").hide();`  вызывается, это дело можно отловить через [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Comment: > з содержимом

с содержимым

> Файл этот стандартный изменять нельзя.

на выбор:

* Это стандартный файл, [его] изменять нельзя [нельзя изменять]
* Файл этот - стандартный, [его] изменять нельзя [нельзя изменять]

> почемуто не находит функцыю

почему-то не находит функцию

Answer (score 2):

У jQuery есть [глобальные события](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/) для ajax событий. Можно ловить завершение поста на /delete/ и через небольшой таймаут считать, что ф-я updateCart отработала.